# Exoplayer 2.5.3 get time when will next song will get play exoplayer android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to get exact `timestamp` when next song will get play.while current song near to end.
I am using

> implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.3'

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp?

Comment: when will next song get play I want exact time for it.

Comment: (System.currentTimeMillis()) + (player.getDuration() - player.getCurrentPosition()) I know this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

On button click I printed logs like that:

```
Log.e("TAG", "Duration: " + (mPlayer.getDuration() / 1000) + "s.");
Log.e("TAG", "Current: " + (mPlayer.getContentPosition() / 1000) + "s.");
Log.e("TAG", "Left: " + ((mPlayer.getDuration() - mPlayer.getContentPosition()) / 1000) + "s.");
```

Here what I got:

D: => onVideoTapped

E: Duration: 287s.

E: Current: 0s.

E: Left: 286s.

D: => onVideoTapped

E: Duration: 287s.

E: Current: 6s.

E: Left: 281s.

### Check again your calculations. Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

I checked it again and it looks that I got the right time:

```
14:43:27 - onVideoTapped()           => onVideoTapped
14:43:27 - log()                     => Duration: 596s.   Current: 595s.
14:43:27 - log()                     => Left: 1s.
14:43:28 - onTracksChanged()         => currentWindowIndex: 1  nextWindowIndex: 2 isPlayBackStateReady: true
14:43:28 - log()                     => Duration: 596s.   Current: 596s.
14:43:28 - log()                     => Left: 0s.
14:43:31 - onVideoTapped()           => onVideoTapped
14:43:31 - log()                     => Duration: 510s.   Current: 2s.
14:43:31 - log()                     => Left: 507s.
```

Comment: after E: Left: 281s. next song needs to get start but it wont that's the issue it always took randomly 100ms to 200ms to get start.